# Retrieve Slack bot access token from Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework, slack, azure-bot-service

I would like to connect to my customer's Slack workspace directly from an application outside Azure Bot Service.

I need to retrieve the access token which was sent to Azure Bot after the authorization was given by the Slack workspace administrator.

How can I retrieve the Slack access token which is stored somewhere in the Azure infrastructure?

Comment: That depends. If the Azure Bot Service is using Managed Identity I'm afraid you won't be able to impersonate the bot's identity. As Another option, you can ask the admin to create o 'login' user so you can use it to authenticate against ad / retrieve a token

Comment: Thank you but I don't get it. I have a simple configuration, no fancy stuff. Where is the slack token stored on Azure? Feel free to give details, I am not an Azure expert.

Comment: Inside Azure AD, you'll find applications, then search for Certificates and Secrets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-credentials

Comment: Why do you want to access Slack from a third-party application using the Bot's token? Wouldn't you want to use a unique token for each service? The other user is correct in that using the Bot's token would be like "impersonating" the Bot.

Comment: That's what I want to do because Azure Bot does not support all the features I need.